# Stimpack versus Combat Shield

Tags: starcraft-2

**A 2 or 3 Barrack rush with either Stimpack or Combat Shield versus any race.**

You sometimes see the pro´s open with this and then expand behind it, or even doing it as an all in.

**But in which situation would it be best with Stim Pack, and in what situaion would it be best with Combat Shield?**

- Stim Pack is more agressive and take longer to research.
- Combat Shields focus on defence, and are faster to research.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This is based on research on the interwebs, not first hand experience*

It depends on what race you are against.

- If you are against protoss then you should be researching [Concussive Shells](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Concussive_Shells) first - Marauders are very strong against Stalkers and Concussive Shells makes kiting Zealots much more effective
- According to [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Marine) Combat Shields are more effective than Stim Packs against Terran

  > In TvT, Combat Shields are actually superior to Stimpacks, all other things being equal. A marine with shields will survive a fight with a standard 'stimmed' marine with 7 HP. Combat Shields also takes less time to research so in early TvT skirmishes one should not get the Stimpack upgrade first by default. In addition, a standard siege tank (unsieged) does 15 damage vs marines so it can kill a 45 HP marine in 3 shots. However, it requires a 4th shot to kill a marine with CS (55HP).
- So the only time you would take research Stim Pack first would be against Zerg

Comment: Yes i totally agree with you, you would only really need stim (early game) vs zerg seeing as zerglings can outrun a marine but with stim and some micro you can easily outrun zerglings.